# Core Data Property Validation in Swift 3

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-data

I'm trying to set up [custom property validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/ObjectValidation.html) for a property belonging to an `NSManagedObject` subclass. According to the docs the general signature for such a method in *Swift 3* is as follows:

```
func validate<Key>(value: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>) throws
```

My property is called `amount`, so I've got:

```
class Transaction: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var amount: Float

    func validateAmount(value: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>) throws {
        // custom validation logic...
    }
}
```

As I understand it, when I create a new Transaction instance, set its `amount` property, and then try to save the managed object context, `validateValue:forKey:` should be called on the relevant instance, which should in turn locate and call my custom validation method. Unfortunately this isn't happening: `validateValue:forKey:` is called, but my method is ignored.

You can see all this for yourself in this [sample project](http://jmp.sh/mVoiHD4) (written in Xcode 8.3.3), and I'd be grateful if someone can tell me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: `func validateAmount(_ value: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>) throws` seems to be the correct signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`func validateAmount(_ value: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>) throws` is called. Add a _ like in `validateValue(_ value`.

Comment: Brilliant! I can now go to bed.

Comment: In Swift 4 I had to mark the method as `@objc` to get it to be called